Не могу написать адекватное движение через Force на Unity2d
Крч, делаю 2d платформер по типу Celeste. Работаю работаю, движени(Run) у меня через velocity, однако из-за этого когда меня допустим кидает батутом(трамплином) в сторону, то нажимая кнопку движения у меня, невероятно, обнуляются все действующие силы, обнуляется скорость и начинается движение ток от метода run. Прямое решение этой проблемы - использовать AddForce вместо velocity, однако, снова, о боже мой, меня проверетело на одном месте. Как бы я не пробовал и у кого бы код не брал, происходит одно и тоже - бесконечное ускорение, медленный разгон, какая-то наркомания и так далее.
Крч, вопрос вот в чём. Как мне пофиксить эту проблему помимо Force-а, чтобы скорость не обнулялась, не сбивалась, а если ток через Force это можно, то как мне написать код/метод через Force чтобы оно работало АДЕКВАТНО и ИГРАБЕЛЬНО, чтобы это рил нормально работало без всякой наркомании, чтобы не бесконечно ускорялось, чтобы норм сразу двигалось, чтобы при прыжке перс не набирал безумную скорость и не улетал в стратосферу или не выходил на орбиту и бла бла бла. Кто-то знает как норм метод(код) движения написать используя AddForce?

Кто-то знает как норм метод(код) движения написать используя AddForce? никак

"АДЕКВАТНО и ИГРАБЕЛЬНО" использовать динамическое тело под контролем симуляции физического движка в роли персонажа платформера? Либо свободная симуляция, либо контроль! Либо крестик сними, либо трусы одень, и рыбку съесть и не сесть не получится.

@Yaroslav Ну еба, чёто во всех остальных играх нормально всё и то чего я пишу добиваются, а тут оказывается нихера невозможно, нельзя и прочее)
Чёт видимо либо я недогоняю, либо вы все нифига не знаете, раз нет ответа на вопрос как сделать эту фигню чтобы не гасилась остальная инерция/движение

@Fufik2000, мой ответ прост как головоломка 4+... либо/либо с указанием на конкретное либо! Для особо затрудняющихся: симуляция не должна влиять на тело персонажа, то есть оно должно быть кинетическим.
